# AWS SAM Template - Local Testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I have a AWS SAM template that I'm trying to test locally and then deploy. The local test runs (sam local start-api) but the payload is not validated. This means that I have a RequestValidator in place, but it does not validate a thing.

Then, I try to deploy the YAML file to AWS to test there, and I get an error that reads:

> "Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete
>   failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED.
>   Reason: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid
>   Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found:
>   1. Resource with id [BoilerPlateFunction] is invalid. Event with id [ApiEvent] is invalid. RestApiId property of Api event must reference
>   a valid resource in the same template."

This is my yaml file, so first I want to be able to make the RequestValidator work in my local and once that is done, to know what I'm doing wrong and why I can't deploy:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20
Parameters:
  operationName:
    Type: String
    Default: testoperationName
  restApiName:
    Type: String
    Default: testrestApiName
  validatorName:
    Type: String
    Default: testvalidatorName
  validateRequestBody:
    Type: String
    Default: testvalidateRequestBody
  validateRequestParameters:
    Type: String
    Default: true
Resources:
  BoilerPlateApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref restApiName
  BoilerPlateFunctionMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: ANY
      RestApiId: !Ref BoilerPlateApi
      RequestValidatorId: !Ref RequestValidator
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.test: true
  RequestValidator:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref validatorName
      RestApiId: !Ref BoilerPlateApi
      ValidateRequestParameters: !Ref validateRequestParameters
  BoilerPlateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: boilerplate/apiName
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BoilerPlateApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
```

So again, that runs using sam local start-api, I can hit the endpoint and the Lambda is executed. But I expect the API gateway to throw an error if I don't include the "test" parameter in the query string, but it does not, it let it go through.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The function has been created before the API Gateway.
You can use **DependsOn** parameter to create the API before the method

So, just change the following in the BoilerPlateFunction resource to:

```
  BoilerPlateFunction:
    DependsOn:
      - BoilerPlateApi
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: boilerplate/apiName
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BoilerPlateApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `sam local start-api` doesn't support request validation. There were discussions about adding this as a feature, but they don't seem to have progressed, see https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/299